# Join two dataset by time range

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Is there a way to join two tables using one table's timestamp difference to match another table's timestamp. For example, for one table I have start and end timestamps, I want to match other tables timestamp in the difference between start and end times.

table1

```
start_time         end_time          ID  Ident
01/01/2022 17:56   01/01/2022 17:59  1   1A
01/01/2022 18:36   01/01/2022 18:40  2   1C
01/01/2022 19:48   01/01/2022 19:50  1   2D
01/01/2022 20:12   01/01/2022 20:14  2   4F
01/01/2022 21:47   01/01/2022 21:50  3   7R
01/01/2022 22:56   01/01/2022 22:59  5   2E
01/01/2022 23:57   01/01/2022 23:59  6   3E
```

Table2

```
Timestamp         rate
01/01/2022 17:57  5
01/01/2022 19:49  5  
01/01/2022 20:14  5
01/01/2022 21:47  5
01/01/2022 23:58  5
```

result

```
start_time         end_time          ID Timestamp         rate
01/01/2022 17:56   01/01/2022 17:59  1  01/01/2022 17:57  5
01/01/2022 18:36   01/01/2022 18:40  2  null              null
01/01/2022 19:48   01/01/2022 19:50  1  01/01/2022 19:49  5
01/01/2022 20:12   01/01/2022 20:14  2  01/01/2022 20:14  5
01/01/2022 21:47   01/01/2022 21:50  3  01/01/2022 21:47  5
01/01/2022 22:56   01/01/2022 22:59  5  null              null
01/01/2022 23:57   01/01/2022 23:59  6  01/01/2022 23:58  5
```

I tried to use pandas.merge_asof in Python but the problem I'm having is there are duplicate rows for the right table in the result which I don't want. Is there a way to do this without duplication maybe in SQL? I have tried inner join but I not getting any change from the table.

Comment: You question is too vague and unfocused, you need to chose a specific language and ask a specific question including your code.

Comment: You really should create a mock example of the type of data you're dealing with, and the output you're getting for that example, and the output you ***want*** for that example.  A good place to start reading about this is here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) *(This will allow you to show the types of duplicates you're referring to, and what you want to be done to prevent those duplicates.)*

Comment: In pandas you can use from merge_asof method for this

Answer (score 0):

> For example, for one table I have start and end timestamps, I want to match other tables timestamp in the difference between start and end times.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table2
    ON  table2.event_timestamp >= table1.start_timestamp
    AND table2.event_timestamp <  table1.end_timestamp
```